# How many votes should I cast in the primary phase?

Tags: support, voting, moderator-election

There are 3 moderator positions, so I supposed that I had 3 votes only. But it seems I have more, perhaps 10 or 30? I did not test it. What is the maximum or recommended number of votes to cast in the primary phase?

Comment: While this is answered in terms of how many votes you *can* cast, I would suggest that you *should* cast votes on the candidates you have an opinion about -- don't vote on everyone just to vote on everyone.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There is no maximum number of votes that you can cast in the primary phase. In fact, you can vote on every candidate, up or down. The primary is designed to weed out candidates before the general election (*that*'s when you only get three votes).

The idea is to narrow down candidates so that when you actually do have a limited number of votes (first, second, and third choice, based on the [STV voting system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_transferable_vote)), you can use those votes effectively.

The top ten candidates in terms of votes from this phase will advance when the primary closes and the general election begins.

Anyone with 150+ rep can vote in either phase.

Comment: It might be useful for this information (regarding the number of votes available) to be displayed somewhere (prominently) on the pages on which one votes.

Answer (score 1):

In primary phase, there is no maximum limit. But yes there is a limit in election phase, that is 3 votes (First, second and third choice).