# Should we update the election page text to include how to cast a vote?

Tags: discussion, support, moderator-election

As a first time voter it really wasn't clear to me how to cast a vote! It also wasn't clear how many votes I could, or should, cast.

We have at least some members also confused by this, see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337872/how-do-i-vote-for-a-moderator-in-the-primary-election) question and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290157/how-many-votes-should-i-cast-in-the-primary-phase).

The problem is that, as a first timer voter, there are at least some who think that the voting mechanism will be somehow separate, or different, to the standard up or down voting one sees for questions and answers.

Furthermore the election page primary page doesn't actually say how many votes one can have in the primary. This is a little confusing.

A little reminder or help text is all that is needed.

I propose we update the election text in the side bar.

Current text:

> In the primary phase, all nominees advance to preliminary community
>   voting. Any community member with 150 reputation may vote in the
>   primary.
>
> There is no commenting in this phase, only one up or down vote per
>   candidate. The candidate vote scores are all public. Initial voting
>   should provide a rough sense of which candidates are most electable.
>
> All candidates are displayed in random order.
>
> The primary is not binding; nominees may withdraw at their discretion
>   at any point during the primary phase.
>
> After 4 days, the top 10 candidates based on primary vote score
>   proceed onward to the election phase.

New text with additions:

> In the primary phase, all nominees advance to preliminary community
>   voting. Any community member with 150 reputation may vote in the
>   primary.
>
> To cast a vote simply vote your nominees up or down the same way you 
>   would up or down vote a question or answer; by using the arrows next to 
>   their name.
>
> During the primary you can cast as many votes as you like. It is not 
>   until the next stage of the election that your total number of 
>   votes will be limited.
>
> There is no commenting in this phase, only one up or down vote per
>   candidate. The candidate vote scores are all public. Initial voting
>   should provide a rough sense of which candidates are most electable.
>
> All candidates are displayed in random order.
>
> The primary is not binding; nominees may withdraw at their discretion
>   at any point during the primary phase.
>
> After 4 days, the top 10 candidates based on primary vote score
>   proceed onward to the election phase.

Comment: I support your idea completely. I will mention it in the chat room.

Comment: I was confused in the nomination phase - SO's sidebar asked me to "cast my vote!" but I found nowhere where I could do that... It took quite some digging to realize the top 30 advance to the primary

Comment: I agree with this post. I would add that the number of votes, be it one or more, that we can cast in the election should be posted there as well. It was very confusing for me as a first time voter. I've been on SO for about 2 years now and didn't now anything about this system. More information is always a good thing, especially when this is, potentially, going to affect the way that I use SO.